# Node fs.readdirsync read directory in npm package

Tags: node.js, express, fs

i tried to use `fs.readdirSync` and it work perfectly, but when i publish to npm and install this package to my new project, it not read my package directory instead it will read from my new project directory.

My goal is to get list file names inside package directory not new project directory

```js
const dirents = fs.readdirSync("./", { withFileTypes: true });
console.log(dirents)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `__dirname` instead of `./`?

Comment: @Phil i'll try it and update the result. Thankyou

Comment: @Phil yes that solution work, i need a little modification because i use ES6 so instead of using __dirname i use `dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));` maybe you want to make an answer and i will mark it as correct answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ensure a local directory with fs.readdir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011508/how-do-i-ensure-a-local-directory-with-fs-readdir)

Comment: idk exactly the question, but yeah the answer is similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `__dirname` because it is an environment variable that tells you the absolute path of the directory containing the currently executing file.

Instead of using `./` it will represent your current working directory